# ARIA additional info to group content for screen reader (figure, div, aside etc.)

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, epub

I'm trying to make text as accessible as possible. I'm wondering if there is a way to mark up structured elements that are visually distinguished from the main text.

Is there a way to put an invisible label on grouped content that is read by a screen reader?

**exhample**

- grouped text thats surrounded by a red box (a div-Element) -the screen reader first reads "Red box"
- a poem in a figure element -the screen reader first reads "Poem"

As I understand,

- **aria-label** it only for interactive elements that replaces it (button)
- **aria-labeledby** is connecting the grouped content with the visible headline
- **aria-describedby** is connecting the grouped content with visible further information

I've read something about aria-description but it doesn't seem to be valid (oxygen doesn't allow it).

Or is the whole idea bad?

Comment: `aria-description` is due to be added in ARIA version 1.3, which might be the reason why it’s not yet supported. `aria-describedby` is quite old and should work, but it requires a visible description.

Comment: Ah thank you for this information. So maybe I can use aria-description in the future.

Comment: Hi Sabine. Did `<section aria-label="red box">` solve the issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a solution in resolving the following misunderstanding

> aria-label it only for interactive elements that replaces it (button)

Also [the region role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#region) and other structural roles (like `table` or `form`) need to carry a label:

> Authors MUST give each element with role region a brief label…

And I believe the purpose of region is what you are looking for:

> […] containing content that is relevant to a specific, author-specified purpose and sufficiently important that users will likely want to be able to navigate to the section easily and to have it listed in a summary of the page.

`region` is the implicit role of a `<section>` element.

If you don’t judge it important enough to be included in the page summary, maybe [the group role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#group) is more suitable.

Usually, when the reading cursor or focus enter a region or group, screen readers announce their accessible name. They will also announce when the grouping has been left.

```html
<section aria-label="Red box" style="padding: .5em; border: 1px dashed red">
  <p>This might get included in a page summary</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</section>

<div role="group" aria-label="Blue box" style="padding: .5em; border: 1px dashed blue">
  <p>This will not get included in a page summary</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought the information wouldn't be important but it seems it is. I need this for epub3. I'm not sure, if these roles are supported there. At https://idpf.github.io/epub-guides/epub-aria-authoring/ the aria-roles always have "doc" infront of it.

Comment: That’s very interesting. I’m not sure whether the _html_ tag is correct, then. I added _epub_ to your tags.
`<section>` already maps to `region`, so you should be fine by simply providing an `aria-label` on a section.

Comment: @SabineR [see chapter 7](https://idpf.github.io/epub-guides/epub-aria-authoring/#sec-covers) of your linked document (: